# Synching Data Multiple AsyncTask to complete

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have two asynctasks. One asynctask is called and the other is called in the onPostExecute of the first one. These tasks happened when the user clicks a button. The problem is task one is started when the user clicks the button fast and didn't wait for the second asynctask to complete yet.

Task 1 -> insert into a column, onPostExecute starts Task 2 -> increment column to insert

What ended up happening when users click too fast is that it runs
Task 1 -> Task 1 -> Task 2 -> Task 2
This resulted in both column insert mapping onto the same column before the columns even incremented (task 2).

How do i fix this? In a way, i want it to be real time, and it should work with multiple users.
I have two different SQL queries, one to update value in a column and one to update current column so next insert is in the next column. I use MYSQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would this be two AsyncTasks to begin with? Sounds like an atomic operation. Better yet, use MYSQL's auto-increment, or have the user create a UUID.

Comment: How do i auto increment if it's not insert operation but update. and also can i reset the value when it reaches a certain number through that way. The users are logged in users. They are unique in the MYSQL database.

Comment: this is kind of a misleading question. it appears you are asking how to sstop a user from executing a task more than once but what you really want to know is how to handle syncing or data across multiple devices. I suggest maybe editing your question to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you should be using transaction here. See: [Using Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

if you don't want to use transaction, another option would be to do a producer/consumer using semaphores. Initalize semaphore with 1 token.  Task 1 would first acquire a semaphore. at the end of task 2, task 2 would release a semaphore. Therefore you are ensuring that only 1 chain can be processing at a time.